# How to get Apache to point to correct httpd.conf file

Tags: apache

I'm trying to set up Apache on my MacOS Mojave 10.14.2; When I run:

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

I get:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 70 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load lib/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so into server:
dlopen(/usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so, 10): image not found
```

Correct me if i'm wrong but shouldn't it go:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

How do I change that?

Comment: No, it is okay as it is. Use some file-manager to check the shared module in question (`mod_authn_file.so`): does it exist at all? Maybe it is somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to resolve the problem

1. Install `mod_auth` package (not sure how it is named in MacOS)
2. comment line 70 of your config file